How do i link the 2024 Google Places API to google sheets to get the details for places?
I have a list of restaurants in google sheets that I have been to and I want to retrieve the reviews or the ratings for the restaurants through the Places API(New). How can I create code that loops through the rows of the names of the restaurants and get details like the price of the restaurant and the reviews?
Most of the help online is regarding the old Places API and I figured that I might as well use the new API since some fields are new and it would be easier to maintain in the longer run.
I wanted to build it using apps script on google's own platform in Javascript as I figured that would be the most native way

Posting my own code here as I could not find any other updated sources referencing the new Places API.
ChatGPT gives code that references the old API and so I edited that to work with the new Places API:
function getRestaurantRating(restaurantName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  // Loop through cells in the range B10 to the last filled row
  for (var i = 10; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var restaurantNameCell = sheet.getRange('B' + i);
    var statusCell = sheet.getRange('E' + i); // Corresponding cell in column E
    
    // Check if the corresponding cell in column E is empty
    if (statusCell.isBlank()) {
      var restaurantName = restaurantNameCell.getValue();

      // Make a request to the Places API to get the details of the restaurant
      var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAXY1ai0iIYYOYvIxGEG1qFqAs6mjGzG-A'; // Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual API key
      var url = 'https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText';
      
      var payload = {
        textQuery: restaurantName
      };
      
      var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Goog-Api-Key': apiKey,
        'X-Goog-FieldMask': 'places.displayName,places.types,places.rating,places.userRatingCount,places.googleMapsUri,places.primaryType,places.priceLevel,places.shortFormattedAddress,places.photos'
      };
      
      var options = {
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: headers,
        payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
      };
      
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());


            
      // Check if the API request was successful
      if (typeof jsonResponse.places !== 'undefined') {
          var name = jsonResponse.places[0].displayName.text;
          //var primaryType = jsonResponse.places[0].primaryType;
          //var photos = jsonResponse.places[0].photos;          
          var googleMapsUrl = jsonResponse.places[0].googleMapsUri;
          var type = jsonResponse.places[0].primaryType;
          var priceLevel = jsonResponse.places[0].priceLevel;
          var userRatingCount = jsonResponse.places[0].userRatingCount;
          
          // Update cells with retrieved details
          var nameCell = sheet.getRange('A' + i);
          //var primaryTypeCell = sheet.getRange('M' + i);
          //var photosCell = sheet.getRange('K' + i)
          var googleMapsUrlCell = sheet.getRange('L' + i);
          var typeCell = sheet.getRange('E' + i);
          var priceLevelCell = sheet.getRange('J' + i);
          var userRatingCountCell = sheet.getRange('H' + i);
          
          nameCell.setValue(name)
          //primaryTypeCell.setValue(primaryType)
          //photosCell.setValue(photos)
          googleMapsUrlCell.setValue(googleMapsUrl);
          typeCell.setValue(type);
          priceLevelCell.setValue(priceLevel);
          userRatingCountCell.setValue(userRatingCount);
      } else {
        return 'Not found';
      }
    }

    }
  }

Hope this helps get started with the new Places API.
